# Custom upload component

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm developing my first application in vaadin. Now I'm trying to customize upload component. In summary I have to do the upload of an image.

Now my component is implemented in a standard way:

```
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,String mimeType) {
// Create upload stream
FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
try {
    // Open the file for writing.
    file = new File("/tmp/uploads/" + filename);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    new Notification("Could not open file<br/>",e.getMessage(),Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE).show(Page.getCurrent());
    return null;
}
return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
 }
```

I want to ask you, if i can do the upload of the document without use a temp file on server.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Of course,

you just need to provide a OutputStream for the upload component.
This could be a a ByteArrayOutputStream for example, so you have everything as a large bytearray.

Just be aware, when the user uploads a 10 GByte size file, you will also need that much memory on the server for that request

André